# Multi-line text box Bullet points

Tags: list, export, multiline-text-field

I have some multi line text boxes in custom lists I have developed. These are rich text to allow the users to format the text such as changing the font colour. The list is then exported to excel and a ppt report created via a macro on this data.

The issue I have is people want to use the bullet point option but this doesn't copy across to excel so I need one of the following options to resolve this:

1. Get excel to show the bullet points (not possible I think)
2. Disable the bullet point and number option on the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you can hide the bullets and numbers element from the form using jquery.The element ID will be something like this - **Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Paragraph-Large-0-0-0** (for a full screen form)

[image]

You can use javascript to set the display style to none to hide this element :

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Paragraph-Large-0-0-0").style.display = "none";
```

Before : 
[image]

After hiding : 
[image]

**Note :** When the form is resized the id of the bullet/number control changes from **Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Paragraph-Large-0-0-0** to **Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Paragraph-Medium-0-0-0**

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do I add the JavaScript into a content editor on the new and edit forms? If so what is the full code I need to enter into the content editor?